# C pipe multiple message only one recieved

Tags: c, pipe, ipc, stdout, stdin

I am trying to send two messages from the parent to the receiver. Only one is received. Receiver uses stdin and stdout for the pipe, and outputs its results into std err. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    char buffer[100]; // The pipe's buffer
    int pipes[2];

    pid_t   childpid;

    if ( pipe(pipes) ){
        fprintf(stderr,"FATAL ERROR IN PIPE");
    }


    if((childpid = fork()) == -1){
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
    }

    if(childpid == 0){
        close(pipes[1]);

        dup2(pipes[0],STDIN_FILENO);

        scanf("%s\n",buffer);
        fprintf(stderr,"REC: %s\n",buffer);
        scanf("%s\n",buffer);
        fprintf(stderr,"REC: %s\n",buffer);
        sleep(50);
    }
    else
    {
        close(pipes[0]);

        // Read in a string from the pipe 
        char* arr = "HelloWorld\n";
        write(pipes[1],arr,strlen(arr)+1);
        write(pipes[1],arr,strlen(arr)+1);  
        sleep(50);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: There are no messages in pipes, just a stream of bytes.

Comment: What do you mean by no message. I have sent the message "HelloWorld\n" twice in the parent process

Comment: Recommend to remove `"\n"` from the format in `scanf("%s\n",buffer);`.  What do you think that `"\n"` does?  Likely a contributer to "Only one is received".

Comment: @Antoun It means "you seem to expect that pipes support distinct *messages*, and can deliver them one at a time, but this is not true, pipes are just streams of bytes". At least that's my interpretation.

Comment: Then how the program knows that this is the end of the message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is with the following line:

```
scanf("%s\n",buffer);
```

`scanf` does not read trailing white space (including new-line characters) unless matched by a directive. But the directive exists here. So it waits for another new line after the usual new line which follows the input.

Remove the `\n` in both the `scanf` statements.

Secondly, you have to modify your `fprintf` statements to add the `\n` in them.

```
fprintf(stderr,"REC: %s\n",buffer);
```

Thirdly, don't add 1 to the `strlen(arr)` in `write`. Modify it to:

```
write(pipes[1],arr,strlen(arr));
```

It works. See [live demo](https://tio.run/##rVLRTsIwFH3fV9zMEFszZJD4ImJCFCKJATJJfMCFjK2DxtItbacSw7djW4YDwoMP3qe707PTe25PXF/E8XZ7QXnMioTAnVQJza6X984RxOj8GCs41fAJby0bap0Tefq7oHxhMIdyBauIcmSaSCxiL15GAq5M/zENsfPtgC4Lzos0JWLa9P2wDY0GTJYEcpqTS1keWaoRMqictsK2Y6GcJjNlVShL9EcJ0xSQpSLLx4B3l5lKcz2iSpG2RITw3H530n2GXhCMAhgMYTwY91zctvSNs5dDaH8DdCDNxDvCGDodqDcPlO1AWjMTyDWcvcy@yBdVqFlpl9KVcgf8A7mYZbI0MG2GuLRmKinyVnngh97L5HEwnPUHz73h6JAl44inyK1J19st8WCc0yUEvYdbqMk3fob7bzqMkBzd@L8LsDthktjmvG//yLdORkCiRAcBIthFDVKRrUCVeYFKRMfKRE3o93KfCGPZayZYogerBvoUVFUL9jTZ06KMcKRbjP9OBDgx2TryKIgqBAdf88DZbLc/):

Output:

```
REC: HelloWorld
REC: HelloWorld

Real time: 2.082 s
User time: 0.043 s
Sys. time: 0.037 s
CPU share: 3.85 %
Exit code: 0
```

Comment: It's a nice hypothesis, but practice doesn't agree (at least on the platform that I tried it on (glibc/linux, cygwin, macos)).

Comment: I did not have compatible platforms to try it out. So I said "likely to solve". Edited the answer a bit.

Comment: It now works after couple of more changes. Updated the answer with live demo.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `strlen(arr)+1` part. You're sending the terminating `nul` as well and that `nul` ends up making up the second "string" read by `scanf`:

```
REC: HelloWorld
REC:
```

If you remove the `+1`, you'll get both lines (I've also decreased the sleep times because I'm not patient enough to wait 50 seconds for the result):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    char buffer[100]; // The pipe's buffer
    int pipes[2];

    pid_t   childpid;

    if ( pipe(pipes) ){ fprintf(stderr,"FATAL ERROR IN PIPE"); }
    if((childpid = fork()) == -1){ perror("fork"); exit(1); }

    if(childpid == 0){
        close(pipes[1]);

        dup2(pipes[0],STDIN_FILENO);

        scanf("%s\n",buffer);
        fprintf(stderr,"REC: %s\n",buffer);
        scanf("%s\n",buffer);
        fprintf(stderr,"REC: %s\n",buffer);
        sleep(2);
    }
    else
    {
        close(pipes[0]);

        // Read in a string from the pipe 
        char* arr = "HelloWorld\n";
        write(pipes[1],arr,strlen(arr)); // << NO +1 
        write(pipes[1],arr,strlen(arr)); // << NO +1
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: It is mentioned almost in every website that this "+1" should be there. ie. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/

Comment: Also there is undefined behavior happens when i remove it. In my big project i use many pipes at the same time. When i remove it and send a message through all pipes. It doesn't reach to all the children !

Comment: @Antoun You have plenty of UB in there (unchecked error codes). Anyway, if you want to keep the nuls there, why not just skip stdio and do raw IO syscalls throughout. stdio has issues. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: it is an assignment i have to use stdio

Comment: @Antoun the +1 is because they purposefully send the terminating nul, to be used as a delimiter. You can do that if you wish, but then it means you must interpret it accordingly on the receiving end.